# svn revert failing

Tags: svn, revert

Why is svn's revert failing for me?

I'm trying to revert to version 6253.

```
$ svn revert 6253
Skipped '6253'
```

I know this is the version I want because I typed the following in to the shell less than an hour ago:

```
$ svn commit -m "before making change X"
Sending        scala/Config.scala
Sending        scala/Entity.scala
Transmitting file data ............
Committed revision 6253.
```

I think something is wrong with the repository because I don't see my commit message when I type `svn log`. All I see is the first 3 commits, which end at `r5650`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`svn revert` throws away local changes to your working copy, so will not do what you want, as the changes are already committed.

To get those files at that specific revision, try `svn update -r 6253 scala/Config.scala scala/Entity.scala` instead.

Comment: What happens if I moved files around? So after R6253, I moved the former `Entity.scala` to `OldEntity.scala` and replaced it with a new implementation? Also, what if I deleted a file without replacing it?

Comment: Copying the contents of `Entity.scala` to `OldEntity.scala` will leave you with 1 new unversioned file (`OldEntity.scala`) and the original file still checked out to revision 6253. If you want to replace it with a new implementation, you'll need to update the file to HEAD revision before you'll be allowed to commit it. Not sure if there's a better way, but I typically update to the older revision, copy the contents of the file elsewhere, update the file to HEAD, paste the old contents back into the file and recommit.